# Can't Read Data from external Server to Hololens

Tags: c#, uwp, tcpclient, hololens

I have written some code to transfer data from external server to Hololens. I am able to connect Hololens to the server. But I am facing problem in sending the data from server to Hololens. Whenever I call `ReadData` function it isn't even connected(it prints Not connected).
I am quite new to `c#` and unity and isn't able to sort out this matter yet.
I am using `StreamSocket` and DataReader classes to connect and read the data respectively. Function `Connect()` connects with the server in `start()` method and then I call `ReadData` function in `update()` method  to get the data from the server at every frame. I am attaching my code file.
Can you help me out in solving my problem Thanks in advance.

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Net;   
using System;  
using UnityEngine;  
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_METRO
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Foundation;
#endif
public class TCPclientRead : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ServerIP = "10.1.2.35";


    [Tooltip("The connection port on the machine to use.")]
    public int ConnectionPort = 11000;

    private string data = "connected" ;

    public TextMesh mesh;
    private bool connected = false;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_METRO

  private StreamSocket networkConnection;

        /// <summary>
        /// Temporary buffer for the data we are recieving.
        /// </summary>
    //private byte[] dataBuffer;


    public void Connect( )
    {
          // Setup a connection to the server.
               HostName networkHost = new HostName(ServerIP.Trim());

              //HostName networkHost = new HostName( IPAddress.Any.ToString());    
              networkConnection = new StreamSocket();

            // Connections are asynchronous.  
            // !!! NOTE These do not arrive on the main Unity Thread. Most Unity operations will throw in the callback !!!
            IAsyncAction outstandingAction = networkConnection.ConnectAsync(networkHost, ConnectionPort.ToString());
            AsyncActionCompletedHandler aach = new AsyncActionCompletedHandler(NetworkConnectedHandler);
            outstandingAction.Completed = aach;    
    }

    public void NetworkConnectedHandler(IAsyncAction asyncInfo, AsyncStatus status)
    {
            if (status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
            {
                connected = true;
                 // Here Just display connected   

            }
            else
            {
                connected = false;    
                Debug.Log("Failed to establish connection. Error Code: " + asyncInfo.ErrorCode);
                // In the failure case we'll requeue the data and wait before trying again.
                networkConnection.Dispose();

            }    

    }


    public void ReadData()
    {
        if(connected)
        {  
            DataReader reader = new DataReader(networkConnection.InputStream);
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            reader.LoadAsync(512);
            data = reader.ReadString(512);

         }

    }


    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>(); 
        Connect();
    }


    private void Update()
    {

        if (connected)
        {     
            mesh.text = data;


        } 
         else
            mesh.text = "Not Connected";
         ReadData();
    }

#endif

}
```

Edit : 1. I have doubt that `ReadData()` needs to be called asynchronously Therefore I updated the code but it isn't working even now.
2. I am using Unity Editor and I have enabled the required settings and I am able to connect to the server. It's just that I am not able to transfer the data.
3. I am using netcat to create server.

My updated code

```
 delegate void DelegateMethod();

    public async void ReadData()
    {
        if(connected)
        {  
            DataReader reader = new DataReader(networkConnection.InputStream);
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            await reader.LoadAsync(512);
            data = reader.ReadString(512);

         }

    }

    public void AsynCall()
    {
        DelegateMethod dlgt = new DelegateMethod(this.ReadData);
        IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke(null, null); 
        dlgt.EndInvoke(ar);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>(); 
        Connect();
    }


    private void Update()
    {

        if (connected)
        { 

           if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                data = "Improper";    

             AsynCall();
             mesh.text = data;            
        } 
         else
            mesh.text = "Not Connected";

    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess you haven't read the complete post I have mentioned desired behaviour (to transfer data), my problem and the associated code. I'll welcome any other suggestion to improve the post.

Comment: Does the call to `Connect` complete / is the callback fired? The docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701509) suggest that `ConnectAsync` should take a service name for the second parameter, not the port.

Comment: yes the callback Is fired that's why the boolean variable `connected` is getting set to `true`.

Comment: The parameter definition says : service name or `TCP port number` of the remote network destination.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you have not enabled the UWP Capability "InternetClient" which would prevent it from actually connecting to the remote server.  You don't mention what tool chain you are using, but if you are in Unity check under Build Settings -> Publish Settings -> Windows Store -> Publishing Settings -> Capabilities.  If you are working in Visual Studio, you can adjust this in the project properties.

Comment: I have enabled these properties and that's why I am able to connect to the Hololens. My problem is whenever I call `ReadData` function it says not connected otherwise it says connected.